# iOS 13/Facebook SDK error "Unable to find a valid UIWindow"

Tags: facebook, ios13, uiwindowscene

(To forestall well-intended suggestions, yes I posted this question last week on Facebook's developer forum. No responses yet.)

**TL;DR**

Facebook SDK 5.8 complains at startup `FBSDKLog: Unable to find a valid UIWindow`.

**The Main Story**

In a from-scratch, one-view Xcode 11/iOS 13 project, there is no longer a default `UIWindow` *member* associated with the application. (The window *per se* is still around; you can see it, contained in a `UIWindowScene`, using the View Hierarchy Debugger in Xcode, or the Reveal app.)

FBSDK 5.8 does seem to be iOS-13-aware, and looks around for it. The relevant code is at line 498 of

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/FBSDKInternalUtility.m.

Facebook's code iterates over the application's `connectedScenes` member, which for me is an empty set. How do I modify my code so that FBSDK finds the window?

**Some Hacking**

I tried adding the following to `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` but it seems to be too late — the FBSDKLog message has already appeared by then. (So I'm flailing...)

```
guard let s = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: s)
```

The following also failed, but it was just a shot in the dark:

```
guard let s = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
self.window = UIWindow(frame: s.coordinateSpace.bounds)
self.window?.windowScene = s
self.window?.rootViewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: @ Andrew Duncan did you find any solution ?

Comment: No have not heard anything, either here or on Facebook's forum. For now it doesn't matter, because I am using projects created with earlier versions of Xcode. But for creating new projects, one workaround could be this collection of older Xcode project templates: https://github.com/rmaddy/XcodeTemplates.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the new behaviour and don't mind reverting to the old way, you can try the following

1. Delete `Application Scene Manifest` key from `Info.plist`

   [image: Key to delete]
2. Delete `SceneDelegate.swift`
3. Add `var window: UIWindow?`to `AppDelegate.swift`

   ```
   import UIKit

   @UIApplicationMain
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

       var window: UIWindow? // <-- Here

       func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   // Override point for customization after application launch.

   //        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()


       return true
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: I don't think it is a valid answer.

Comment: It's help me. Works from me. This solution is only works when you bypass scene delegate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `window` variable to `AppDelegate` class

   ```
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

   var window: UIWindow?
   ```
2. Assign `UIWindow` inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        if let window = window {
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
            self.window = window
        }

        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
             application,
             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        )

        return true
    }
   ```